# Cant delete all records using WCF rest service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am using WCF Rest service. I am trying to delete multiple records from the repository called "_altProductVersionEntityRepository"
Here is my entire code below

```
 public Result UpdateProductObject(ProductObjectToSave prodSave)
    {

        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork((IObjectContext)_objectSetFactory);

        var versions = prodSave.VersionDetails;
        var altVersions = prodSave.AlternateVersionDetails;



        foreach (var versionDetail in versions)
        {
            var detail = versionDetail;

            var dbVersionentity = _productVersionEntityRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == detail.Id);


            var altVersionEntity = _altProductVersionEntityRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductVersionEntityId == detail.Id);

            if (dbVersionentity == null)
            {
                dbVersionentity = new ProductVersionEntity();
                _productVersionEntityRepository.Insert(dbVersionentity);
                dbVersionentity.Id = GetNextTableId("vProductVersion");
                dbVersionentity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;


            }


            dbVersionentity.Name = detail.Name;
            dbVersionentity.Code = detail.Code;


            if (detail.Id > 0){

            _productVersionEntityRepository.Update(dbVersionentity);
                if (altVersionEntity != null){
                    _altProductVersionEntityRepository.Delete(altVersionEntity);
                }
            }



        }


        try
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return new Result() { Status= e.Message };
        }

        return new Result() { Status= = "Record updated successfully" };

    }
```

In variable "altVersionEntity" i try to find first record from "_altProductVersionEntityRepository" repository. In this repository there are multiple records but it only delete single record as i am doing FirstOrDefault here. What is way to delete all records. I am using FirstOrDefault because i want to delete records only if they are find otherewise it will throw error.
What is way to delete multiple records? I am still new to WCF so please help me.

Comment: Any answers guys? Did i provide incorrect info?

Comment: I really need solution for this. Please please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find my own solution. What i do i use find method instead of FirstOrDefault which i was using in above code. I use find method like below

```
 var altVersionEntity =
                _altProductVersionEntityRepository.Find(x => x.ProductVersionEntityId == detail.Id);
```

Then i use variable altVersionEntity and convert to list and then loop through it and delete records from "altProductVersionEntityRepository" repository one by one like below

```
var tempList = altVersionEntity.ToList();
                    for (i = 0; i <tempList.Count ; i++)
                    {
                        _altProductVersionEntityRepository.Delete(tempList[i]);
                    }
```